# Синхронизация и передача данных CoreData между контроллерами

Tags: swift, coredata, uiviewcontroller, передача-параметров

```
    Всем привет! У меня возник вопрос, как передавать данные из разных контроллеров в Entity? В приложении есть несколько контроллеров. По мере перехода от одного контроллера к другому инициализируются свойства Core Data. На данный момент данные, полученные в одном контроллере, пропадают при переходе на следующий. Как их сохранить и передать в другой контроллер? Вариант с массивом мне не подходит, кроме как в ScheduleViewController, где я отображаю список занятий. Мой код:
         '''
        //Здесь данные сохраняются
            private var teacher = Teacher()
            private var student = Student()
            
            override func viewDidLoad() {
                super.viewDidLoad()
               
                teacher = Teacher(context: context)
                student = Student(context: context)
            }
            
            private func savePassword () {
                
                if let text = teacherPasswordTextField.text,
                   text.count > 5 {
                    
                    do {
                        
                        teacher.name = teacherNameLabel.text
                        teacher.password = text
                        student.teacher = teacher
                        teacher.customers?.adding(student)
                        try context.save()
                        
                    }
                    
                    catch {
                        print(error.localizedDescription)
                    }
                }
            }
                  
          extension TeacherSignInViewController: UITextFieldDelegate {
            
            func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
                savePassword()
                textField.resignFirstResponder()
                return teacherPasswordTextField.text!.count > 5
            }
        }
        '''
        // А здесь нет
         private func setUpTextFields () {
                nameTextField.delegate = self
                nameTextField.keyboardType = .namePhonePad
                
                passwordTextField.delegate = self
                passwordTextField.keyboardType = .namePhonePad
                
                /* MARK: Uncomment this line when publishing */
                // passwordTextField.isSecureTextEntry = true
                
            }
            
            private func fetchData () {
                
                guard teacher.name != nil,
                    teacher.password != nil
                
                else {
                    return
                }
                
                do {
                    
                    student.name = nameTextField.text
                    student.password = passwordTextField.text
                    try context.save()
                }
                
                catch {
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                }
                
            }
        }
        
        extension RegistrationViewController: UITextFieldDelegate {
            
            func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
                
                guard let text = textField.text else { return false }
                
                if textField == nameTextField && text.count > 3 {
                    passwordTextField.becomeFirstResponder()
                }
                
                if textField == passwordTextField && text.count > 5 {
                    textField.resignFirstResponder()
                }
             
                fetchData()
                
                return nameTextField.text!.count > 3 && passwordTextField.text!.count > 5
            
        }
        }
        '''
       
        @IBAction private func completionButtonTouchUpInside(_ sender: UIButton) {
        
                delegate?.lessonViewControllerDidSet(self)
                  dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
                
            }
        
        '''
         //Сюда переходит учитель после регистрации. Его данные после перехода сбрасываются
extension ScheduleViewController: LessonViewControllerDelegate {
            
            func lessonViewControllerDidSet(_ vc: LessonViewController) {
              
                let lesson = Lesson(context: context)
               
                lesson.date = vc.datePicker.date
                lesson.time = vc.timePicker.date
                lesson.subject = vc.subjectTextField.text
                
                guard 
                    teacher.name != nil,
                    teacher.password != nil
                else
                {
                    return
                }
                
                teacher.addToSchedule(lesson)
                lesson.teacherSchedule = teacher
                
                do {
                    try context.save()
                }
                catch {
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                }
          
     DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
    
      '''
        
          [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/V2Zb4.png
          [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uMHu1.png
```

Comment: У вас при вызове getTeacher каждый раз создается новый учитель, а в getLesson нужно его не создавать, а доставать из контекста (fetch) с его уроками.

Comment: @OlegSoloviev, спасибо

Comment: К сожалению, таблица по-прежнему пуста

Comment: @OlegSoloviev, хотел уточнить, что данные CoreData не передаются, а инициализируются в LessonViewController

Comment: @OlegSoloviev, мне кажется, что fetchRequest используется, когда данные уже получены, поэтому я решил уточнить момент связи между LessonViewController и Entity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
private func getLesson(for index: Int) -> Lesson? {

    let fetch: NSFetchRequest<Lesson> = Lesson.fetchRequest()
    var lessons = [Lesson]()

    do {
        lessons = try context.fetch(fetch)
    }
    catch {
        debugPrint(error.localizedDescription)
    }
    guard lessons.count > index else { return nil }
    return lessons[index]
}
```

Но вам еще нужно прописать связку Учитель -> Уроки

Comment: я добавил строку lessons.count > index, но ошибка не исчезла. Связку(relationship) между учителем я прописал в самой базе(xcdatamodel)

Comment: Скопируйте полностью функцию getLesson(for index: Int) из моего ответа

Comment: Ошибка исчезла, результат не появился

Comment: Значит, у вам нет lessons, скорее всего.

Comment: Вы были правы по поводу того, что массив lessons пуст. Я писал о том, что entities инициализируются при получении данных из контроллера. Не могли бы Вы мне подсказать, как сохранить полученные данные между переходами с одного контроллера на другой?

Comment: я обновил код, но данные между контроллерами по-прежнему не передаются

Comment: Если вы сохраняете данные в CoreData в одном из контроллеров, то в другом контроллере вы их просто фетчите (выбираете, достаете) и всё, специально передавать их не нужно, они хранятся в CoreData. Просто убедитесь, что данные сохранились.

Comment: порядок передачи данных немного сложнее. Не все переменные инициализируются сразу в одном контроллере. Как инициализировать оставшиеся свойства, сохранив значения предыдущих? Я слышал, что CoreData сохраняет значения при обращении из разных частей программы, но результата я так и не получил

Comment: то есть, тут несколько задач: 1. Сохранить существующие данные между переключениями контроллеров и инициализировать оставшиеся. 2. Передать нужные

Comment: и спасибо за Ваши комментарии

Comment: кстати, где уместно(как в tableview), я использую fetch. Но, как я уже писал выше, данные, полученные в предыдущем контроллере, не передаются. При попытке их получить мне пишут, что они равны nil

Comment: я понимаю, что надоел Вам своими спорами, но не могли бы Вы помочь с решением задачи? Текст вопроса и код я обновил

Comment: Мне нечего добавить к тому, что я уже писал. Если хотите, выложите проект на гитхаб, киньте ссылку, я посмотрю.

Comment: спасибо за предложение. Извините, что так долго не отвечал. Я пытался выложить свой проект на Github. Там какие-то сбои

Comment: https://github.com/IvanNextToJunior/CoreDataDemo-2. Если у Вас на гитхабе такое же имя пользователя, как здесь, то я могу Вас добавить

Comment: 404. А куда репозиторий делся?)

Comment: никуда. Надеюсь, что я Вам приглашение отправил)

Comment: Да, второе приглашение сработало.

Comment: Поправил код проекта.

Comment: Иван, когда вы пишете let teacher = Teacher(context: context) или let student = Student(context: context), вы тем самым каждый раз создаете новую запись учителя или студента в базе данных. А вам нужно создавать ее только, когда необходимо, во всех остальных случаях нужно брать ее из базы данных.

Comment: Понятно. Спасибо

Comment: я хотел бы узнать, почему Вы два раза инициализируете массив lessons и обновляете таблицу?

Comment: но спасибо Вам еще раз за код. Вы мне очень помогли

Comment: вернее, с кодом я разобрался: там его один раз можно вызвать. Но ещё раз спасибо за Ваше решение

Comment: Второй раз массив lessons не инициализируются, а обновляется (фетчится заново), т.к. после добавления появляются новые lessons и их нужно отобразить в таблице. После этого обновляется таблица с новыми lessons. Это обновление можно вынести в отдельную функцию и вызывать ее во viewDidLoad и после добавления нового lesson.

Comment: понятно, спасибо